# Как добавить эффект к кнопке?

Tags: css, всплывающее-окно

Как этой кнопке сделать эффект при наведении, что бы просветлялась например или загоралась другим цветом?

```
<p align="right">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cfJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + "cdn-main.123contactform.com/includes/tinybox/tinybox.js.minified.js?2dd7b05' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<link href="//www.123contactform.com/includes/tinybox/tinyboxstyle.css.minified.css?2dd7b05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<a href="javascript:"  style="display:scroll;z-index:10;bottom:210px;left:2px;" onclick="var tinybox_width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth; tinybox_width=Math.round(tinybox_width*0.6);TINY.box.show({iframe:'http://www.123contactform.com/form-2169330/-',boxid:'frameless',width:tinybox_width,height:500,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40})"><img border="0" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/acfb6e3f8f7771c1c4cd0c74a9822ec9/1472759469/599/1065900/PRYPer.gif"></a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Просветляется":

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: .75;
}
```

```html
<p align="right">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cfJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + "cdn-main.123contactform.com/includes/tinybox/tinybox.js.minified.js?2dd7b05' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<link href="//www.123contactform.com/includes/tinybox/tinyboxstyle.css.minified.css?2dd7b05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<a href="javascript:"  style="display:scroll;z-index:10;bottom:210px;left:2px;" onclick="var tinybox_width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth; tinybox_width=Math.round(tinybox_width*0.6);TINY.box.show({iframe:'http://www.123contactform.com/form-2169330/-',boxid:'frameless',width:tinybox_width,height:500,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40})"><img border="0" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/acfb6e3f8f7771c1c4cd0c74a9822ec9/1472759469/599/1065900/PRYPer.gif"></a>
</p>
```

Цвет меняет:

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}

a:hover span{
  background: red;
}

a span {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: .67rem;
  height: 39px;
  line-height: 39px;
  width: 102px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #28292e;
}

a img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p align="right">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cfJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + cfJsHost + "cdn-main.123contactform.com/includes/tinybox/tinybox.js.minified.js?2dd7b05' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>

<link href="//www.123contactform.com/includes/tinybox/tinyboxstyle.css.minified.css?2dd7b05" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<a href="javascript:"  style="display:scroll;z-index:10;bottom:210px;left:2px;" onclick="var tinybox_width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth; tinybox_width=Math.round(tinybox_width*0.6);TINY.box.show({iframe:'http://www.123contactform.com/form-2169330/-',boxid:'frameless',width:tinybox_width,height:500,fixed:false,maskid:'bluemask',maskopacity:40})">
  <img border="0" src="http://i.piccy.info/i9/acfb6e3f8f7771c1c4cd0c74a9822ec9/1472759469/599/1065900/PRYPer.gif">
  <span>заказать звонок</span>
  </a>
</p>
```